# split string with more than one Char in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

i want to split the String = "Asaf_ER_Army" by the "ER" seperator.
the Split function of String doesn't allow to split the string by more than one char.

how can i split a string by a 'more than one char' seperator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It does. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx).

```
string source = "[stop]ONE[stop][stop]TWO[stop][stop][stop]THREE[stop][stop]";
string[] stringSeparators = new string[] {"[stop]"};

// Split a string delimited by another string and return all elements.
string[] result = source.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Edit:
Alternately, you can have some more complicated choices (RegEx). Here, http://dotnetperls.com/string-split.

Answer (score 6):

[`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) does do what you want. Use the overload that takes a string array.

Example:

```
string[] result = "Asaf_ER_Army".Split(
    new string[] {"ER"},
    StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Result:

```
Asaf_
_Army
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of String.Split which takes a string array as separators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1bwe3zdy%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Unless you are using framework < 2?