# String split algorithm

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string. I want to split this sentence to smaller strings with given string array.

For example:

The input string is `"Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8"` and i want to split this without `["word2, word7, word4"]`

The output would be like

```
"word1"  
"word3"  
"word5 word6"  
"word8"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you already tried something? If so, where are you stuck?

Comment: [**What have you tried?**](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: you have one of the methods that you need in your question .. Split()
google how to use the Split() method in C#

Comment: also if you look to the right of this page under Related, there are tons of links that you can click on and utilize

Comment: possible duplicate of [split string with more than one Char in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880475/split-string-with-more-than-one-char-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [String.Split Method (String[],  StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) method.

```
var inputString = "Word1 Word2 Word3 Word4 Word5 Word6 Word7 Word8" ;
var separators = new []{"word2", "word7, "word4"};
var output = inputString.Split(seperators,StringSplitOptions.None);
```